# Search Realm objects with UITextField

Tags: ios, search, uitextfield, realm

I have a list of Realm objects that i want to search for using a `UITextField`. I added the search feature on a `UITableViewController`, and now i want to search for these objects using a `UITextField` where the user enters few letters and then the objects start appearing under it. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

To use a `UITextField` instead of `UISearchController` which forces the use of a `UISearchBar`, you would simply setup a delegate to respond to the `UITextField` delegate method:

```swift
textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```

Then like the answer above says, filter your objects in Realm with the text from the text field:

```swift
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "propertyToFilterOn contains[c] %@", textField.text!)
let realm = try Realm()
filteredObjects = realm.objects(ObjectClassName).filter(predicate)
```

Finally, use the collection of `filteredObjects` as the data source for your `UITableView` to show the list to the user. Make sure that you re-run the search after every call to the `UITextFieldDelegate` and `reloadData` on the `UITableView` to keep the UI in sync.

Comment: What does it differ from the way i did it ? What i did was add an action for the textField Editing Changed, then used NSPredicate

Answer (score 1):

Apple provides for the purpose of searching and filtering in table views a component called `UISearchController`. This provides you a lot of predefined functionality and user interaction and integrates nicely in the look and feel of the platform.

But because wiring that up with a `UITableViewController` and Realm yourself can be a little tedious, there is an open-source component [`ABFRealmSearchViewController`](https://github.com/bigfish24/ABFRealmSearchViewController) out there which saves you some work, so that you don't have to reinvent the wheel here. Looking into this component, I guess you will gain some insight what you would need to do to either use that or `UISearchController` directly. In advance there are tutorials how to get started with the component for [Swift](https://realm.io/news/building-an-ios-search-controller-in-swift/) and [Objective-C](https://realm.io/news/building-an-ios-search-controller-in-objective-c/).

Comment: Yes, i've jaed the RealmSearchViewController where a search bar appears. But now i need to search for objects using a UITextField

Answer (score 1):

I used an `NSPredicate` with `contains[c]` and the text that is inside the `UITextField` and then provided a Results object by filtering `realm.objects(*Class*)` with that predicate

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "fullName contains[c] %@", textField.text!)
let realm = try Realm()
patientsList = realm.objects(*ClassName*).filter(predicate)
```